# ios 11 - wrong update button in App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an issue related to update new version in iOS 11. 
I have created a function to detect new version and prompt user to update via configuration file. This function works perfect so far.
But after upgrading to iOS 11, when I tap on Update Now of alert popup, then AppStore is opened, the status of button is Open instead of Update, even thought current version of app on AppStore is 2.0 and current version of app in device is 1.0 !?!
I guest user has opened App Store previously and AppStore has cached content for next use. Finally, the bug is occurred! This is just my thinking!

If you got this issue or you have any ideas on this issue. Please share with me.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it also happened to me. when an app is updated, and I can not install the latest version, it shows me OPEN not UPDATE on AppStore, and I have to uninstall the app, download new app on AppStore, and it is the latest version.

I think the reason why we can not download the lastest app version is AppStore needs time to update its database, or maybe it has cache or somthing.

Comment: That's great! Me too, same as you :D